# Trigger an event when the scrollbar is used

Tags: javascript

I've been wondering if there's a way to trigger an event when the scrollbar is used.

For example when the user is grabbing the scrollbar or when the user is clicking somewhere all along the height of the scrollbar container.

Thank you very much

Comment: What have you tried? The clicking is irrelevant (or why should it be?). You know, you can also scroll with the keyboard... mousewheel, etc etc. What you need is the `"scroll"` Event Listener.

Comment: I'd be pretty happy to find only one solution of what I asked, even on google. I'm not talking about the basic "scroll" event. I'm talking about an event directly related to the scrollbar selection. So yes I have seen all those links and not only one answer my question.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want that? What is your exact task, issue? Maybe you have an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: I'm working on a smooth scroll and I think it could be pretty rad not hacking the basic behavior of the scrollbar.

Comment: If you're creating a smooth scroll, but want to tap into the default scroll behavior you might run into an endless loop. If you know that a default scrollbar (on desktop) is ~17px width...  what stops you from using the viewport mouse position? Without any code this question seems too broad.

Comment: Yes but you don't consider Mac user. On Mac the scrollbar is not always visible. So I'd like to know when the native scrollbar is hovered.